# Импорт части SQL дампа в базу

Tags: sql, dump

Есть SQL дамп размером в 5ГБ.

Есть ли возможность импортировать из SQL дампа только схему таблиц и 5-10 записей для каждой таблицы? Или, может, есть решение, чтобы уменьшить сам SQL дамп и сохранить в нем только схему таблиц и по несколько записей для каждой таблицы?

Answer (score 0):

`--where` option allows to specify limit:

`mysqldump YOUR_DATABASE --where="1 LIMIT 10"`

Comment: Актуально лишь при полном отсутствии FK.

Comment: Для вопросов и ответов на английском - есть другой раздел сайта.